# Does knowing Latin help learning English?

Tags: history, language

I have read that one who knows Latin has a good command over English. Is this correct or just a myth? If it is correct, how does it work?

Comment: Not in any significant way. English is **not** a [Romance language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages)

Comment: also, see [History of English in 10 minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3r9bOkYW9s)

Comment: Depends on how good (or doubleplusungood) your English classes are.

Comment: I think that learning any other language can help you with your English, if you're taught it well. I don't know whether Latin will help you any more than any other language.

Comment: @Biju Jose - You should try asking on English.SE, as they'll have a lot more knowledge concerning the etymology of the language. English isn't a Romantic language (Latin/Greek based) like Italian, French, Spanish, etc. English is a giant mish-mash of blended languages, based more on Germanic sentence structures than Romantic and English uses *a lot* of borrowed words. "Water" has its roots in the Germanic "Vasser", but Aquaduct (a tube that carries water) refers to "water" as "aqua" which is a bit of borrowed Latin. Latin might help with about 20-30% of English words, as a very rough estimate.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some examples](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) of places where this claim is being made.

Comment: Related: [Does learning Latin first dramatically improve the ability to learn more languages?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19497/8192)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a [widely-cited study on the English lexicon](http://www.getcited.org/pub/101646962), close to 60% of English words are of French or Latin origin. At the very least, a knowledge of Latin would increase your comprehension of the English language, particularly when it comes [words that are longer than two syllables](http://www.classics.uiuc.edu/programs/latin/why/).

The National Committee for Latin and Greek maintains that students who study Latin in high school do [significantly better on their SAT scores](http://www.promotelatin.org/why-latin-and-greek/facts-figures-resources), especially in the areas of reading and composition. (However, that could also be because Latin is not usually taught in your average public high school.)

Finally, bilingualism of any sort has all kinds of beneficial cognitive effects. A good summary of the critical literature on that topic [here](http://www.dana.org/news/cerebrum/detail.aspx?id=39638#_ENREF_4).

Answer (score -2):

Latin defininitely improves English vocabulary.  The higher SAT scores on the verbal part of the test can be explained by that fact

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/5) to support your claims.

Comment: Correlation is not the same as causation. And it may be a classical example of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias